# Pygame. Не работает метод spritecollideany()

Tags: python, pygame

Я делаю игру где игрок может управлять машинкой и ему навстречу движутся другие машинки. Ему надо не допустить столкновения. И для этого я использую спрайты и группы. Есть класс игрока и класс (или спрайт) машинок. Они находятся в одной группе. Но при добавлении условия ниже программа сразу же закрывается. Никаких ошибок не выводит.

```
if pg.sprite.spritecollideany(hero, cars):
    sys.exit()
```

Может я не правильно понял работу метода? Или использую его не так?
Если нужен дополнительный код напишите, что именно

Comment: Смотрели https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/sprite.html#pygame.sprite.spritecollideany? А какой тип у `cars`? Судя по описанию функцию должен быть `pygame.sprite.Group`

Comment: Эээ, но `sys.exit()` и должен закрывать программу же. Или условие срабатывает даже без столкновения?

Comment: Да, как только я открываю программу, она закрывается.